# Join issue typeorm

Tags: typescript, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am trying to do a join with two entities with typeorm. These are the entites:

```
@Entity()
export class Power {
    @PrimaryColumn({
        type: 'uuid',
    })
    id: string
    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
    })
    name: string
    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
    })
    description: string
    @Column({
        type: 'varchar',
        enum: ['artificial', 'natural', 'inherited'],
    })
    type: string
}
```

And the other is:

```
@Entity()
export class Own {
    @ManyToOne(() => Heroe)
    @JoinColumn({
        name: 'idHeroe',
    })
    heroe?: Heroe
    @Column({
        type: 'uuid',
        nullable: true,
    })
    idHeroe?: string
    @ManyToOne(() => Villain)
    @JoinColumn({
        name: 'idVillain',
    })
    villain?: Villain
    @Column({
        type: 'uuid',
    })
    idVillain?: string
    @ManyToOne(() => Power)
    @JoinColumn({
        name: 'idPower',
    })
    power: Power
    @PrimaryColumn({
        type: 'uuid',
    })
    idPower: string
}
```

I try to make this query:

```
        const powers = await this.ownDB
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .innerJoinAndSelect(PowerDB, 'power', 'power.id = Own.idPower')
        .where('Own.idVillain = :idVi', {
            idVi: id.value,
        })
        .getMany()
```

But I only obtain this result:

```
[
Own {
idHeroe: null,
idVillain: '6f79fd0f-1dfe-477f-b28b-9d155d806e22',
idPower: '8ca2d435-62bb-4032-90b4-e0924a199340'
}
]
```

I can't get the power, I tried these query in postgres and the join works. These is the sql query:

```
SELECT "Own"."idHeroe" AS "Own_idHeroe", "Own"."idVillain" AS "Own_idVillain", "Own"."idPower" AS "Own_idPower", "power"."id" AS "power_id", "power"."name" AS "power_name", "power"."description" AS "power_description", "power"."type" AS "power_type" FROM "own" "Own" INNER JOIN "power" "power" ON "power"."id" = "Own"."idPower" WHERE "Own"."idVillain" = $1
```

And this is how I do the inserts:

```
            this.ownDB.insert(
            this.ownDB.create({
                idVillain: aggregate.id.value,
                idPower: power.id.value,
            }),
        ),
```

I don't know why the join don't work in the ORM but in postgres works. Thanks.